# How to address data imported with pandas?

Tags: python, variables, pandas, error-handling

I am using pandas to import some .dta file and numpy/sklearn to do some statistics on the set. I call the data `sample` I do the following:

```
#   import neccessary packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn as skl

#   import data and give a little overview (col = var1-var5, 20 rows)
sample = pd.read_stata('sample_data.dta')
print('variables in dataset')
print(sample.dtypes)
print('first 5 rows and all cols')
print(sample[0:5])

# generate a new var
var6 = sample.var1/sample.var3
```

I get an error if I adress a variable by its name directly (`var1` vs. `sample.var1`). I find it a little tedious to always include `sample.`. Is there any nice way to call the variables directly by their name?

Comment: `var1 = sample.var1` ?

Comment: I could surely do that..but isn't their a better way? In the data set I have >500 var :(

Comment: Note that the variable created will not be a copy at first but some modifications will break the relationship between that Series and the DataFrame. This is risky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this contrived example. Usually I don't like messing with `locals()` and `globals()` but I don't see a cleaner way:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 1
        self.var2 = 2

obj = A()

locals().update(obj.__dict__)

print(var1)
print(var2)
>> 1
   2
```

Since you are working with a dataframe you will have to loop through `df.columns` instead of `__dict__`. Your code will be something along the lines of:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1]})

for col in df.columns:
     locals().update({col: df[col]})

print(a)
>> 0    1
   Name: a, dtype: int64
```

You should be very careful when doing this , as this will overwrite any variable you may have already defined with the same name, eg:

```
import pandas as pd

a = 7

print(a)
>> 7

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1]})

for col in df.columns:
     locals().update({col: df[col]})

print(a)
>> 0    1
   Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! That would do. Does the issue result from the `.dta` format? I believe one is able to call the vars directly if one uses `.csv` instead...

Comment: @RachelSleeps I'm affraid I'm not following your question, but if you are using a `.csv` file you may parse it with [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) which will parse each line directly to a dictionary

Comment: I tried it out and it works very well. Thank you very much!... Yet, it seems too dangerous to me in this particular case. I'll stay with the more tedious version of `dataset_name.var_name`.

Comment: @RachelSleeps DeepSpace gave you the absolute perfect answer to your question.  However, what your asking to do seems to be a very bad idea.  If you have 500+ columns, all those columns are happily encapsulated in a neat namespace of `sample`, I see no good reason to make it un-neat.  If it's convenience your are concerned with, try renaming the variable or assigning a new one `s = sample`.

Comment: that's precisely what I did. I get the data from an external source. Quite an inconvenience to begin with - since var names differ from time to time. Thanks you all!